# Change all "display: none" to "display: block" with Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I have a webite where I want to change all the elements with `"display: none"` to `"display: block"`. I want to automate the action with Python Selenium. I already found methods for doing this, but that only works if you have the class name and if there is only one element you want to change.

Comment: you could just open your website files in visual studio code and do a search for  `display: none` then replace it with `display: block` it's gonna be a lot easier

Comment: You said you wanna do it with python while there's a javascript tag in your question. does that mean that people can give solutions in js either?

Comment: @MahmoodKiaheyrati The solution I found for one element uses JavaScript in a python file, so I thought this would be the same.

Comment: @vooxe it'd be a good idea too include that solution either. and are there just inline stylings or there're some css stylings which you wanna change?

Comment: Are you actually using selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, but it's going to consume a lot of time. It's best if you can narrow down the elements by a more specific xpath:

```
every_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*")

for element in every_element:
    display_prop = element.value_of_css_property('display')
    if display_prop == 'none':
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", element)
```